# Conditionally Splitting Dataframes Using ifelse

Tags: r

I have a large dataset called "inputs".  One of the columns in the dataset is a flag called "constrained" with either "Y" or "N".  I want to create two datasets where one is the rows where the flag is "Y" and one is the rows where the flag is "N".

I tried:

```
ifelse(inputs$constrained == "N",unconstrained <- inputs,constrained <- inputs)
```

but both datasets unconstrained and constrained are identical to inputs.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `ifelse` is designed to return a vector. You cannot use it as the programming construct you are attempting. Arguably your construction should have thrown an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
first <- split(inputs, inputs$constrained)[1]
second <- split(inputs, inputs$constrained)[2]
```

If you wanted to use "[" you could do this:

```
 unconstrd <- inputs[ inputs$constrained == "N" , ]
 constrd <-  inputs[ ! inputs$constrained == "N" , ]
```

Both of that second option might have entries where 'constrained' is NA, due the screwy way that R handles NA conditionals although it would not be a faithful reflection of those rows. (I admit I did not sure what the split method does with NA's.) I just tested the split method and it might be superior, since (like `subset`) it does not return the `is.na(input$constrained)` rows.